# Why ggplot2 duplicate fill legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my data frame:

```
df1<-structure(list(Country_name = c("Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Cyprus", 
"Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Cyprus", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
"Denmark", "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", "Finland", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Greece", "Iceland", 
"Iceland", "Iceland", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Ireland", "Ireland", 
"Ireland", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Luxembourg", 
"Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Malta", "Malta", 
"Malta", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", 
"North Cyprus", "North Cyprus", "North Cyprus", "North Cyprus", 
"Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Norway", "Portugal", "Portugal", 
"Portugal", "Portugal", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Sweden", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", 
"Switzerland", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
"United Kingdom"), Regional_indicator = c("Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", "Western Europe", 
"Western Europe", "Western Europe"), continent = c("Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe"), 
    variables_names = c("lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", 
    "Logged_GDP_per_capita", "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", 
    "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", "lowerwhisker", 
    "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita", 
    "lowerwhisker", "Ladder_score", "upperwhisker", "Logged_GDP_per_capita"
    ), variables_values = c(7.22880411148071, 7.29419994354248, 
    7.35959577560425, 10.742823600769, 6.79613399505615, 6.86350011825562, 
    6.93086624145508, 10.6736392974854, 6.05981206893921, 6.15899991989136, 
    6.25818777084351, 10.4057025909424, 7.57995510101318, 7.64559984207153, 
    7.71124458312988, 10.774001121521, 7.747633934021, 7.80870008468628, 
    7.86976623535156, 10.6392669677734, 6.59014940261841, 6.66379976272583, 
    6.73745012283325, 10.5842227935791, 7.00600481033325, 7.0757999420166, 
    7.14559507369995, 10.7328186035156, 5.42301368713379, 5.5149998664856, 
    5.6069860458374, 10.1323261260986, 7.38765287399292, 7.50449991226196, 
    7.62134695053101, 10.7725591659546, 7.01556777954102, 7.09369993209839, 
    7.17183208465576, 11.1609783172607, 6.30255556106567, 6.38740015029907, 
    6.47224473953247, 10.4818363189697, 7.17703056335449, 7.23750019073486, 
    7.29796981811523, 11.4506807327271, 6.68860197067261, 6.77279996871948, 
    6.85699796676636, 10.5338382720947, 7.39442825317383, 7.44890022277832, 
    7.50337219238281, 10.8127117156982, 5.43546724319458, 5.53550004959106, 
    5.63553285598755, 10.4057025909424, 7.41971874237061, 7.48799991607666, 
    7.55628108978271, 11.0878038406372, 5.8067102432251, 5.9109001159668, 
    6.0150899887085, 10.2637424468994, 6.31799125671387, 6.40089988708496, 
    6.48380851745605, 10.462926864624, 7.28248071670532, 7.35349988937378, 
    7.42451906204224, 10.7587938308716, 7.49127197265625, 7.55989980697632, 
    7.62852764129639, 10.9799327850342, 7.09166288375854, 7.16450023651123, 
    7.23733758926392, 10.6001348495483)), row.names = c(NA, -84L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

When I change the colors of the stacked bar the colors are changed. But the problem is when I set new names for my labels the legend is duplicated.

Why this is happening?

This is my code:

```
ggplot(df1) +
           geom_bar(aes(x = variables_values, y = Country_name,
                        group = Country_name, linetype = variables_names,
                        fill =  variables_names),
                    stat = 'identity', 
                    lwd = 0.71,
                    width = 0.5,
                    position = 'stack') +
  
            scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','blue','green','red'), labels = letters[1:4])
```

Comment: Get rid of `linetype = variables_names` as it's not needed and the other legend is referring to that. 

Also, are you sure you need the group aesthetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `aes` other than `x` and `y` adds another `legend` accordingly, if you specify `aes(..., linetype = var, fill = var)` you will get one `legend` per level of the specified variables.

Therefore, as also mentioned in the comments, you will need to keep only a single `aes`, unless you are working with high dimensional data.

```
ggplot(df1) +
        geom_bar(
                aes(x = variables_values, y = Country_name,
                    fill =  variables_names),
                stat = 'identity',
                lwd = 0.71,
                width = 0.5,
                position = 'stack'
        ) +
        
        scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'red'),
                          labels = letters[1:4])
```

[image]